# Plotting the Convergence Results of scipy.optimize.differential_evolution

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, genetic-algorithm, scipy-optimize

I have two dataframes (df_1, df_2), some variables (A,B,C), a function (fun) and a global, genetic optimiser that finds the maximum value of fun for a given range of A,B,C.

```
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'O' : [1,2,3], 'M' : [2,8,3]})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'O' : [1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3],
                     'M' : [9,2,4, 6,7,8, 5,3,4],
                     'X' : [2,4,6, 4,8,7, 3,1,9],
                     'Y' : [3,6,1, 4,6,5, 1,0,7],
                     'Z' : [2,4,8, 3,5,4, 7,5,1]})

# Index
df_1 = df_1.set_index('O')
df_1_M = df_1.M
df_1_M = df_1_M.sort_index()

# Fun
def fun(z, *params):
    A,B,C = z
        
    # Score
    df_2['S'] = df_2['X']*A + df_2['Y']*B + df_2['Z']*C
    
    # Top score
    df_Sort = df_2.sort_values(['S', 'X', 'M'], ascending=[False, True, True])
    df_O    = df_Sort.set_index('O')
    M_Top   = df_O[~df_O.index.duplicated(keep='first')].M
    M_Top   = M_Top.sort_index()
        
    # Compare the top scoring row for each O to df_1
    df_1_R = df_1_M.reindex(M_Top.index) # Nan
    T_N_T  = M_Top == df_1_R

    # Record the results for the given values of A,B,C
    df_Res = pd.DataFrame({'it_is':T_N_T}) # is this row of df_1 the same as this row of M_Top?
        
    # p_hat =         TP / (TP + FP)
    p_hat = df_Res.sum() / len(df_Res.index)
    
    print(z)
        
    return -p_hat[0]

# Bounds
min_ = 0
max_ = 1
ran_ge = (min_, max_)
bounds = [ran_ge,ran_ge,ran_ge]

# Params
params = (df_1, df_2)

# DE
DE = differential_evolution(fun, bounds, args=params)
```

It prints out [A B C] on each iteration, for example the last three rows are:

```
[0.04003901 0.50504249 0.56332845]
[0.040039   0.5050425  0.56332845]
[0.040039   0.50504249 0.56332846]
```

To see how it is converging, how can I **plot** A,B,C against iteration please?

I tried to store A,B,C in:

```
df_P = pd.DataFrame({0})
```

while adding to fun:

```
df_P.append(z)
```

but I got:

```
RuntimeError: The map-like callable must be of the form f(func, iterable), returning a sequence of numbers the same length as 'iterable'
```

Comment: Sadly you need to find a way to apply dimension reduction on your ABC as 4 dimension plot is not yet a thing... Using the means of ABC may works for example.

Comment: That with the means sounds interesting, how do I do that please? I had imagined that A,B,C could all go in the y axis with iteration on the X axis but your idea sounds easier to read, having just the one line. My problem is logging the result each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I am not sure to have found the best way, but I found one.
It uses the fact that list are pass by reference. That means that if you pass the list to the function and modify it, it will be modified for the rest of the programme even if it is not returned by the function.

```
# Params
results = []  # this list will hold our restuts
params = (df_1, df_2, results)  # add it to the params of the functions

# now in the function add the output to the list, Instead of the mean here I used the distance to the origin (as if you 3 value were a 3d vector) 

p_hat = df_Res.sum() / len(df_Res.index)

distance_to_zeros = sum([e**2 for e in z]) ** 1/2
results.append(distance_to_zeros)
# Indeed you can also append z directly.

# Then after DE call
DE = differential_evolution(fun, bounds, args=params)

x = range(0, len(results))

plt.scatter(x, results, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using RomainL's code to plot A,B,C:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'O' : [1,2,3], 'M' : [2,8,3]})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'O' : [1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3],
                     'M' : [9,2,4, 6,7,8, 5,3,4],
                     'X' : [2,4,6, 4,8,7, 3,1,9],
                     'Y' : [3,6,1, 4,6,5, 1,0,7],
                     'Z' : [2,4,8, 3,5,4, 7,5,1]})

# Index
df_1 = df_1.set_index('O')
df_1_M = df_1.M
df_1_M = df_1_M.sort_index()

# Fun
def fun(z, *params):
    A,B,C = z
        
    # Score
    df_2['S'] = df_2['X']*A + df_2['Y']*B + df_2['Z']*C
    
    # Top score
    df_Sort = df_2.sort_values(['S', 'X', 'M'], ascending=[False, True, True])
    df_O    = df_Sort.set_index('O')
    M_Top   = df_O[~df_O.index.duplicated(keep='first')].M
    M_Top   = M_Top.sort_index()
        
    # Compare the top scoring row for each O to df_1
    df_1_R = df_1_M.reindex(M_Top.index) # Nan
    T_N_T  = M_Top == df_1_R

    # Record the results for the given values of A,B,C
    df_Res = pd.DataFrame({'it_is':T_N_T}) # is this row of df_1 the same as this row of M_Top?
        
    # p_hat =         TP / (TP + FP)
    p_hat = df_Res.sum() / len(df_Res.index)
    
    results.append(z)
        
    return -p_hat[0]

# Bounds
min_ = 0
max_ = 1
ran_ge = (min_, max_)
bounds = [ran_ge,ran_ge,ran_ge]

# Params
results = []
params = (df_1, df_2, results)

# DE
DE = differential_evolution(fun, bounds, args=params)

# Plot
df_R = pd.DataFrame(list(map(np.ravel, results)), columns=('A','B','C'))
plt.figure()
ax = df_R.plot()
ax.set_ylim(min_,max_)
```

[image]